# jQuery val() failing on dynamically generated input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following dynamically created HTML block:

```
<form class="standard settingsPage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="account" style="background-color: rgb(61, 80, 133);">
<h2>Add New Account</h2>
<p>
<label class="" disabled="true">E-mail address:</label>
<input id="accountEmailAddress" class="" type="text" value="" name="accountEmailAddress"/>
</p>
<p>
<label class="" for="accountEmailPassword">Password:</label>
<input id="accountEmailPassword" type="password" name="accountEmailPassword"/>
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input type="button" onclick="checkEmailSettings();" value="Send" name="submit"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Mail Server:</label>
<input id="mail2server" type="text" name="mail2server"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Mail Type:</label>
<select id="mail2type" name="mail2type">
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label>Mail Security:</label>
<select id="mail2security" name="mail2security">
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label>Mail Server Port:</label>
<input id="mail2port" type="text" name="mail2port"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Mail Username:</label>
<input id="mail2username" type="text" name="mail2username"/>
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input id="mailsend" type="button" name="mailsend" onclick="checkEmailSettings();" value="Send"/>
</p>
</form>
```

Which is appended to an existing form.

However when I do $('#mail2server').val() it returns blank, even if there is something in the box.  If I do $('#mail2server').attr('name') it returns the name, so it definitely recognizes that the element exists.  Any ideas why this would be failing?

Cheers,
Gazler.

EDIT

```
function checkEmailSettings()
{
    var emailAddress=$("#accountEmailAddress").val();
    var emailPassword=$("#accountEmailPassword").val();
    var datastring = "emailaddress="+emailAddress+"&emailpassword="+emailPassword;
    if (additionalInfo == 1)
    {
        var mailserver = $("#mail2server").val();
        var mailtype = $("#mail2type").val();
        var mailsecurity = $("#mail2security").val();
        var mailport = $("#mail2port").val();
        var mailusername = $("#mail2username").val();
        alert($("#mail2server").val());
        datastring += "&mailserver="+mailserver+"&mailtype="+mailtype+"&mailsecurity="+mailsecurity+"&mailport="&mailport+"&mailusername="+mailusername;
    }
    $('input[type=text]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('input[type=password]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "checkemailsettings.php",
        data: datastring,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000, 

        success: function(data){
        switch(parseInt(data))
        {
                //SNIPPED
        case 4:
         alert("More information needed.");
         if (additionalInfo == 0)
        {
         var string = addTextToForm("Mail Server","mail2server");
         string += addOptionsToForm("Mail Type","mail2type", new Array("IMAP", "POP3"));
         string += addOptionsToForm("Mail Security","mail2security", new Array("NOTLS", "TLS", "SSL"));
         string += addTextToForm("Mail Server Port","mail2port");
         string += addTextToForm("Mail Username","mail2username");
         string += addButtonToForm("Send","mailsend", "checkEmailSettings();");
         alert(string);
         $('form[name=account]').append(string);
         additionalInfo = 1;
        }
          break;
        }
        },
    });
}

    function addTextToForm(strLabel, strID, strVal)
    {
    if (!strVal) {return "<p><label>"+strLabel+":</label><input id=\""+strID+"\" type=\"text\" name=\""+strID+"\" /></p>";}
        return "<p><label>"+strLabel+":</label><input id=\""+strID+"\" type=\"text\" name=\""+strID+"\" value=\""+strVal+"\"/></p>";
    }
    function addButtonToForm(strLabel, strID, functionName)
    {
        return "<p class=\"submit\"><input id=\""+strID+"\" value=\""+strLabel+"\" onclick=\""+functionName+"\" type=\"button\" name=\""+strID+"\"/></p>";
    }

    function addOptionsToForm(strLabel, strID, optionsArr)
    {
        var returnstring="<p><label>"+strLabel+":</label><select id=\""+strID+"\" name=\""+strID+"\">";
        for (i=0; i<optionsArr.length; i++)
        {
            returnstring += "<option>"+optionsArr[i]+"</option>";
        }
        returnstring += "</select></p>";
        return returnstring;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've got more than one input element with the "id" value "mail2server"? (Or any other element of any type with the same "id" value?)

Comment: Nope. definitely just the one.

Comment: Well ok then, what happens when you call "document.getElementById('mail2server')" and look at the "value" attribute?  That's all that jQuery will be doing.

Comment: That is also returning blank, I have updated the code to show the full form in use (output from firebug.)

Comment: I'm quite sure you have two elements in that case. Can you show the code you are using to append the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "alert" call says `$('#mailserver')`, not `$('#mail2server')`

Comment: This is true, but it is still not retrieving the value.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: OK well there are two possibilities: (1) You've discovered a browser bug, which causes an input element with a value to not work properly when you try to access the value from javascript, or (2) when you fetch what you think is the input element in question, you're actually getting something else.  What is the element type you get from the element with id "mail2server"?

Comment: The type is [object Object] more obscurely, if I assign it a value via the input tag (input id=mail2server value=whatever) then it will return the value.

Comment: If you type something into the "mail2server" input - or what you think to be that input - and then look at the DOM with Firebug, what do you see?

Comment: It won't show inputs for input boxes in firebug or chrome inspector for me.  I think I might just work around it my having the content there by default but hide it and then show it instead of dynamically generating the content.  Doesn't make the error any less annoying though.

Comment: Won't show inputs?  You must be working in some alternate reality then. Firebug definitely and always shows me input elements, and it shows me what I've typed into them.

Comment: Ah, apologies, you are correct, the value displayed in the DOM tab is the one that I have typed in.  I am just going to hide the form elements and display them.  Answer accepted for your time and persistence with the matter though.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  Good luck.  If you ever figure it out I'd be curious as to what the deal is :-)

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample page that dynamically added the code you had above and everything worked just fine.  There must be something else going on, perhaps in the function that your submit button is calling?

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me too on a sample, which made me think it was something to do with being added dynamically.  Cheers for the input though, submit button code added to the initial post.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good to add "return false;" at the end of the onclick attribute in the input buttons.